# String Interpolation vs binding in sqlite. Which one is better?

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

Is there any difference between string interpolation and binding in sqlite. 
which one would perform better

```
let firstName = "Aashish"
"Select * from employee where firstName = \(firstName)"
```

or

```
"Select * from employee where firstName = ?"
sqlite3_bind_text(statement,1,firstName.cString(.utf8),-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT)
```

Comment: "string interpolation" == prone to SQL injection attack

Comment: https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: what about speed ??

Comment: Please explain why speed is so much more important than data integrity and/or data storage reliability that you consider to consciously accept a wide open attack vector. Only consider that if you can read Martins reference and really joyfully laugh, while looking at your database project at the same time.

Comment: It is often the case that code that doesn't check for boundary conditions runs faster. In your specific case, the speed difference is probably minuscule compared to the time it takes to run a select, so not worth considering adding a critical security bug to your codebase.  There aren't many absolute DON'Ts in programming, but building SQL from string interpolation is one of them

Comment: String interpolation is likely to be slower.

Comment: The example code you posted in your question is another reason (besides security) why you should never use string interpolation. Your first example doesn't even build a valid query. Always use binding. It solves several issues.

Comment: Thank you all. I would go with binding method.